# How to represent the lack of widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a container where I want to display border with the condition, If the condition is true then display the border else do not display.

something like this:-

```
bool condition1;
bool condition2;

content: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        top: condition1 ? BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
          width: 1,
        ) : null,
        bottom: condition1 ? BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
          width: 1,
        ) : null,
      ),
    ),
   child: Container(),
   ),
```

but i cant pass the `null`, its giving error.

another way I could do is to make width 0.0, but the border does not go completely. so I want to remove the border widget.

so, if we cant use `null` then how to represent the lack of widget in a flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BorderSide.none` instead of null.

```
Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
         top: condition1 ? BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
            width: 1,
          ) : BorderSide.none,
         bottom: condition1 ? BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
            width: 1,
         ) : BorderSide.none,
       ),
    ),
   child: Container(),
),
```

Refer [BorderSide.none](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderSide/none-constant.html) for more details.

Comment: ok, thanks, I didn't know about `BorderSide.none`. But what if there were no widget like that, then is there any solution for `How to represent the lack of widget in flutter?`. just thinking out of the box.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha For most of the widgets, you can use null as lack of that widget. For example. In your child: Container(), you can write child: null. For this case (Border), the implementation specifically requires that data to be non-null. You can see the assertion here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border/Border.html